# parse json data in angular controller

Tags: json, angularjs, controller

I get this json data by `$http.get` and did the assigning like this `$scope.a = data.a`,how to access x? when I print `a` in console it shows `[object Object],[object Object]` , shouldn't it be `[object Object Object],[object Object Object]` ? And when I use `$scope.a[0].x[0]`, it says undefined. Any idea how to solve it?

```
{
    "a": [{
            "x":1385118661279,
            "y":{
                "y1":25,
                "y2":"12"
            },
            "z":[
                {
                    "z1":20
                },
                {
                    "z2":23
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "x":1385118650279,
            "y":{
                "y1":25,
                "y2":"32"
            },
            "z":[
                {
                    "z1":21
                },
                {
                    "z2":22
                }
            ]
        }],

    "b": "text"
}
```

Comment: well a contains an array but x doesn't, so wouldn't `$scope.a[0].x` be what you want?

Comment: thanks, you are right. i was having trouble with `z`, I thought i could do `$scope.a[0].z.z1` but z is an array, so `$scope.a[0].z[0].z1` worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

means it is an array of objects. the brackets above does not refer to array, it simply means it is an object.

For your next question, the nested 'x' is not an array. You can access it by:

```
$scope.a[0].x
```