# parse json data property in angular controller

Tags: angularjs

After reading this posts:
[parse json data in angular controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896243/parse-json-data-in-angular-controller)

Here is my problem

I have a controller like this

```js
(function() {
  var SomeController = function($scope, someService, $log, $routeParams, ShareData) {
    var colors = function(data) {
      $scope.Colors = data;
      $scope.result = angular.fromJson(data);
      alert($scope.result);

    };

    var errorDetails = function(serviceResp) {
      $scope.Error = "No connection to server";
    };
    someService.colors().then(colors, errorDetails);

  };

  app.controller("SomeController", ["$scope", "someService", "$log", "$routeParams", "ShareData", SomeController]);

}());
```

This alert returns [object Object],[object Object]
When I try to parse one property of this object it returns undefined.

Here is the code.

```js
(function() {
  var SomeController = function($scope, someService, $log, $routeParams, ShareData) {
    var colors = function(data) {
      $scope.Colors = data;
      //here it returns undefined
      $scope.result = angular.fromJson(data);
      alert($scope.result[0].path);

    };

    var errorDetails = function(serviceResp) {
      $scope.Error = "No connection to server";
    };
    someService.colors().then(colors, errorDetails);

  };

  app.controller("SomeController", ["$scope", "someService", "$log", "$routeParams", "ShareData", SomeController]);

}());
```

The service is OK and it returns two complex objects which have a property named path.

Comment: What do you want `$scope.result` to look like? Array of paths or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alert returns `[object Object],[object Object]` - it means that `data` is array of objects. So you don't have to parse anything to get data, it's already parsed.

For example, you can access `path` of the first object in array or construct array of paths:

```
var colors = function(data) {
  $scope.Colors = data;

  // path from the first object in array
  $scope.result0 = data[0].path;

  // array of paths
  $scope.result = data.map(function(obj) {
     return obj.path;
  });
};
```

Comment: $scope.result0 = data[0].path; is still returning undefined.

Comment: Awesome. got it. P was upper case in property.

Answer (score 0):

You're not not being very descriptive with your question.

*Here's a tip...*

Set a breakpoint where the [object Object] is appearing and checkout what your getting.

Comment: Sorry I can't vote you up. The system doesn't allow me.